# Have a function change the DOM while in the function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jquery

I'm using an application that does two steps during a jquery click event. 
1. Changes the CSS properties of an element with a sprite and color attribute
2. Runs a function that iterates scanning the page.

Is it possible to have the page make the css changes and show it in the browser, then run the iteration?

The css changes are made by adding classes and removing classes to the elements.

```
onBtn.click(function(event){
    if(clicked['mon'] == 0){
        monBtn.attr("class", "active");
        clicked['mon'] = 1;
        dow['mon'] = 1;
    }
    else {
        monBtn.removeClass("active");
        clicked['mon'] = 0;
        dow['mon'] = 0;
    }
        checkIfButtonsAreClicked();
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But do you have a question regarding your existing code? If so, please post it, otherwise, please revise your question to be about something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the screen to update before running some other code, you could set the code to fire in 0ms:

```
makeCSSChanges();
setTimeout(function () {
    // The browser will only run this callback once it's taken a breath and
    // done its usual behind-the-scenes stuff.
    scanThePage();
}, 0);
```

When a timeout is set for 0ms, most browsers will do their usual behavior (redraw the page, go about their business, etc.), *then* take care of scheduled events.

In most cases, though, the delay wouldn't be noticeable enough to matter. If the delay *is* significant, then we're approaching the kind of delay that can also lag out the whole browser. Careful.

Comment: This only worked partially.. I had to add 30 instead of 0 as the argument for the css to change first.